# Trying to read pickle file - EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached

Tags: python

I am trying to open a pickle file in Windows called `tradeopt.pars` using the following:

```
import os
import lzma
import pickle
from shutil import rmtree

def main():
    wk_dir=r"C:\Users\stacey\Documents\scripts\open binary file"
    loaded_pars,sim_settings=pickle_load(os.path.join(wk_dir,'tradeopt.pars'),'lzma')

def pickle_load(filePath,compression=None):
    open_cmd=open if compression is None else __import__(compression).open
    with open_cmd(filePath,'r') as f:
        output=pickle.load(f)
    return output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ("Ctrl+C pressed. Stopping...")
```

However I get the following error:

```
EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached
```

I have tried to construct a pickle load method called `pickle_load` without success.  How can I read the file in plain text?

The full error can be seen below:

```
runfile('C:/Users/simon/Documents/scripts/open binary file/open_binaryfile.py', wdir='C:/Users/simon/Documents/scripts/open binary file')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-64-6cf936d5ddfd>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/simon/Documents/scripts/open binary file/open_binaryfile.py', wdir='C:/Users/simon/Documents/scripts/open binary file')

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/simon/Documents/scripts/open binary file/open_binaryfile.py", line 28, in <module>
    main()

  File "C:/Users/simon/Documents/scripts/open binary file/open_binaryfile.py", line 14, in main
    loaded_pars,sim_settings=pickle_load(os.path.join(wk_dir,'tradeopt.pars'),'lzma')

  File "C:/Users/simon/Documents/scripts/open binary file/open_binaryfile.py", line 19, in pickle_load
    output=pickle.load(f)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\lzma.py", line 191, in peek
    return self._buffer.peek(size)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\_compression.py", line 68, in readinto
    data = self.read(len(byte_view))

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\_compression.py", line 99, in read
    raise EOFError("Compressed file ended before the "

EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-64-6cf936d5ddfd>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/simon/Documents/scripts/open binary file/open_binaryfile.py', wdir='C:/Users/simon/Documents/scripts/open binary file')

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/simon/Documents/scripts/open binary file/open_binaryfile.py", line 28, in <module>
    main()

  File "C:/Users/simon/Documents/scripts/open binary file/open_binaryfile.py", line 14, in main
    loaded_pars,sim_settings=pickle_load(os.path.join(wk_dir,'tradeopt.pars'),'lzma')

  File "C:/Users/simon/Documents/scripts/open binary file/open_binaryfile.py", line 19, in pickle_load
    output=pickle.load(f)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\lzma.py", line 191, in peek
    return self._buffer.peek(size)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\_compression.py", line 68, in readinto
    data = self.read(len(byte_view))

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\_compression.py", line 99, in read
    raise EOFError("Compressed file ended before the "

EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached
```

Comment: This probably means the file is corrupted. "File ended" as in no more contents + "before the end-of-steam marker was reached" as in parser cannot see where data should end = data is cut-off

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: Plus [see the posting advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68924328/trying-to-load-pickle-file-attributeerror-cant-get-attribute-individual-on) on your similar, later question.