# Trying to load pickle file - AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'Individual' on <module 'deap.creator'

Tags: python

I am trying to open a pickle file called `tradeopt.pars` using the following code:

```
import os
import lzma
import pickle
import sys
from shutil import rmtree

def main():
    wk_dir=sys.path[0]
    loaded_pars,sim_settings=pickle_load(os.path.join(wk_dir,'tradeopt.pars'),'lzma')
    print(sim_settings)

def pickle_load(filePath,compression=None):
    open_cmd=open if compression is None else __import__(compression).open
    with open_cmd(filePath,'r') as f:
        output=pickle.load(f)
    return output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ("Ctrl+C pressed. Stopping...")
```

However I am getting an error:

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'Individual' on <module 'deap.creator' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/deap/creator.py'>
```

I saw a post that suggested this was a Windows issue so have also tried to run this in Linux without success.  What should I do to read the pickle file?

The full error output is:

```
$ python3 open_pickle_file.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "open_pickle_file.py", line 31, in <module>
    main()
  File "open_pickle_file.py", line 16, in main
    loaded_pars,sim_settings=pickle_load(os.path.join(wk_dir,'tradeopt.pars'),'lzma')
  File "open_pickle_file.py", line 22, in pickle_load
    output=pickle.load(f)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'Individual' on <module 'deap.creator' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/deap/creator.py'>
```

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: Hi Stacey. I note that your questions still have a needy, pleading feel to them, and to me it sounds like you want readers to do your work for you. I am still of the view that if you ask questions confidently, and with the implication you plan to do the bulk of the work, you will get more respondents.

Comment: I wonder if you stick to this mode of asking, that you and I will be stuck in this silly dance forever - I edit your question and paste some boilerplate advice, readers see signs of trouble and elect not to answer, you have to go without help, you ask a new question featuring more begging, I edit your new question and paste more advice...